# How can I debug code for APIService

Tags: ios, swift, passcode

I'm a newbie in creating an sign in using API in swift. I followed a video tutorial from treehouse but I used different version of Xcode and swift. I don't know what will I put in these code. Hope you could help me Or can you give me any references that I could use in creating a sign in page that will input passcode in textfield and submit to validate if the code is existing and will post data. Thank you so much. [image: Error in the Image]

When I click *Fix* these line of code appeared

```
final class EventAPIClient: APIService {
func JSONTaskWithRequest(request: URLRequest, completion: (JSON?, HTTPURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> JSONTask {
    <#code#>
}

init(config: URLSessionConfiguration) {
    <#code#>
}


let  configuration: URLSessionConfiguration
lazy var session: URLSession = {
return URLSession(configuration: self.configuration)
}()

private let token: String

init(config: URLSessionConfiguration, APIKey: String) {
    self.configuration = config
    self.token = APIKey
}

convenience init(APIKey: String) {

    self.init(config: URLSessionConfiguration.default, APIKey: APIKey)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to begin to resolve this issue, you need to look at what [protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) are.

Focusing on information relevant to this situation, they essentially define the signature of a function (among other things). The name of the protocol and the function signature leave clues as to what a given function's implementation should be. This is easily illustrated by a simple example:

```
protocol MathematicalOperations {
    func add(_ int: Int, to int: Int) -> Int
}

class Calculator: MathematicalOperations {
    func add(_ intA: Int, and intB: Int) -> Int {
        return intA + intB
    }
}

// Usage
let calculator = Calculator()
let sum = calculator.add(15, and: 10)
print(sum) // 25
```

tying it back into your situation. The protocol `APIService` has defined the functions like so:

```
protocol APIService {
    func JSONTaskWithRequest(request: URLRequest, completion: (JSON?, HTTPURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> JSONTask
    init(config: URLSessionConfiguration)
}
```

Your `EventAPIClient` class tells the compiler it means to conform to the `APIService` protocol:

```
final class EventAPIClient: APIService {
```

In order to conform to the protocol, `EventAPIClient` needs to provide an implementation for all the definitions in `APIService`.

As for solving the issue, there are some missing pieces of information regarding the definition of JSONTask etc. However, here is an example implementation that should, if nothing else, give you a starting point:

```
func JSONTaskWithRequest(request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (JSON?, HTTPURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> JSONTask {
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, response, error as NSError?)
        } else if HTTPResponse.statusCode == 200 { // OK response code
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? JSON
                completion(json, response, nil)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                completion(nil, response, error)
            }
        } else {
            completion(nil, response, nil) // could create an error saying you were unable to parse JSON here
        }
    }
    return task as? JSONTask
}

init(config: URLSessionConfiguration) {
    self.configuration = config
    self.token = "APIKey" // put your default api key here, maybe from a constants file?
}
```

I hope you find this helpful :)